# Reacts: how to deal with side effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a conception of a survey website and I"m facing problem with side effect at the re-rending

I"m storing objects questions in an array my problem is that when I'm trying to delete a question in the aray the questions at following index  are also deleted

**survey.js**

```
const quest = {
        label: '',
        typeofquestion: "Radio",
        rank: "",
        questionFlag: '',
        min: '',
        max: "",
        choices: [{
            label: ""
        }]
    }
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([quest])
// add question
const addQuestion = () => {
        setQuestions(old => [...old, quest])
    }

//delete

const deleteQuestion = (index) => {
        setQuestions(old => {

            old.splice(index, 1)
            return [...old]
        })
    }
```

Please whicj approach can I use to deal with that problem ?

Comment: Use `setQuestions(old => old.filter((_, i) => i !== index))` instead

Comment: Like @ChrisG, another way is to use `setQuestions(old => [...old.slice(0, index), ...old.slice(index + 1)])`. I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but when you do `old.splice(index, 1)`, it modifies `old`, which isn't something you should do.